# Search for a multiple patterns in specific column in fixed length file and output entire line

Tags: grep

I need a command in Unix to look for a pattern in specific columns in a fixed length file and output the entire line to a different file.

Example File1

```
2345abcdef450022677
1234sdfght350022677
3456abcdef350022677
```

I need extract the lines if column 5 to 10 = abcdef and column 15 to 16 = 22.

I want the output file to have the following data.

```
2345abcdef450022677
3456abcdef350022677
```

I can use the cut command with grep to find the pattern but not sure how to output the entire line.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$ cat foo
2345abcdef450022677
1234sdfght350022677
3456abcdef350022677
$ grep -E '^.{4}abcdef.{4}22' foo >foo2
$ cat foo2
2345abcdef450022677
3456abcdef350022677
$
```

or

```
$ awk 'substr($0,5,6)=="abcdef" && substr($0,15,2)=="22"' foo >foo2
$ cat foo2
2345abcdef450022677
3456abcdef350022677
$
```

or even

```
$ grep '^....abcdef....22' foo >foo2
$ cat foo2
2345abcdef450022677
3456abcdef350022677
$
```

and finally, using sed (checks that 5th to 10th is abcdef and 15th to 16th is 22 and if not deletes the line, credit to user112638726 for this)

```
sed '/^.\{4\}abcdef.\{4\}22/p;d' foo
```

Comment: Add my command to your answer if you want, pretty much the same thing and probably better to have one comprehensive answer. I'll delete mine if you do :)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the grep -E did not work for me... ( Worked fine with example but not with the actual file). The awk command worked great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In sed

```
sed '/^.\{4\}abcdef.\{4\}22/p;d' file
```

Checks that 5th to 10th is abcdef and 15th to 16th is 22 and if not deletes the line